# How to adjust the learning rate of the optimiser in Flux Julia

Tags: deep-learning, julia, flux

As mentioned I tried to implement a learning rate decay for my neural network. I set up the model as follows:

```
nn = Chain(Dense(10,5),Dense(5,1))
opt = Adam(0.01)
opt_state = setup(opt, nn)
```

I tried to adjust the learning rate directly from `opt_state`. Then I found that `Optimisers.Adam` is an immutable struct in the `opt_state` but if I changed the `eta` in `opt` it worked fine.

```
opt_state.layers[1][:weight].rule.eta = 0.001 # ERROR: setfield!: immutable struct of type Adam cannot be changed
opt.eta = 0.001 # no error
```

Furthermore, accessing the learning rate like this doesn't look great. Is it possible to modify the learning rate of the `opt` without setting up a new `opt_state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `adjust!(opt_state, 0.001)` described here: https://fluxml.ai/Optimisers.jl/dev/#Adjusting-Hyperparameters